# Why does it not bring up the terminal window?

Tags: java, loops

For some reason, this code snippet in the main method I made to fill an array of 50 with random integers seem to not respond. It just says that the Java Virtual Machine is running, but never stops.

```
    int[] randomInts = new int[50];
    int i = 0;
    int random = (int) ( 75 - ( Math.random() * 126));
    while( i < randomInts.length)
    {
        randomInts[ i ] = (int) ( 75 - ( Math.random() * 125));;            
    }
    while( i < randomInts.length) 
    {
        System.out.println( randomInts[i] + "\t");
    }
```

Comment: It looks like endless loop. Where is i++ ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to increment `i` in your loops. Otherwise how will it ever be greater than or equal to than `randomInts.length`?

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about the increment. I'm used to for-loops making it do it automatically. Thx Micheal

Comment: @AngelMartinez No problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
while( i < randomInts.length)
{
    randomInts[ i ] = (int) ( 75 - ( Math.random() * 125));;            
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have an incrementation of `i` on each iteration, there fore the condition `i < randomInts.length` is always true, so it goes forever